# How create a personal node c-lighting for create a new channel with other node

Tags: lightning-network, core-lightning

I want to create my personal node to create a new channel with another personal node, an example my node with URL 12345678@192.164.1.7 I want create a channel with another personal node.

I could not found some reference for this problem, can you help me for creating my personal node?

I try to add and parameter to command line `--addr` but this I think is not enough, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you will need to decide which machine will fund the channel. In the current implementation only one party can lock funds to a multi-sig address. Let's say the machine that will fund the channel is A and the other is B. Now open the c-lightning in the terminal on machine B and type `lightning-cli getinfo`. It will give you a bunch of information. Look for the `id` and `address`. Then open the c-lightning on your machine A's terminal and type  `lightning-cli connect id@address:9735`. Where `id` and `address` are the info that you got from the `getinfo` command on machine B.

After connection has been established, you can then open the channel using the command `lightning-cli fundchannel id satoshi [feerate] [announce]` on your machine A. Here `id` is the node id of the node with whom you want to open the channel and satoshi is the amount of bitcoins in satoshis that you want to use to fund the channel. If you want to keep your channel private you can set `announce` to false.

If you want to expose the node to the internet and use the internal IP addresses you can do so by adding `bind-addr=<internal_IP>` and `announce-addr=<public_IP>` in the config files. You can also pass these commands in the terminal when starting the lightningd daemon, but it is easier to do it in config file so that you don't have to do it everytime you start the daemon.

Comment: if I want to create my personal node? with a node id and an ip?

Comment: @vincenzopalazzo what do you mean a personal node? A node that is not announced?

Comment: Yes, I want create an channel on my node

Comment: @vincenzopalazzo Can you explain with more clarity as to exactly what you are trying to achieve? I'm trying to understand your issue better.

Comment: Mh yes, I want to create on the channel with node c-lightning X on my node c-lightning Y in the local network, my question is how to configure the node Y for accepting the command connect to node X

Comment: @vincenzopalazzo I have updated my answer, let me know if you need anything else.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/97929/discussion-between-vincenzopalazzo-and-ugam-kamat).